# I need a stand alone python interpreter/compiler!

Tags: python, compiler-construction

Ok so i am in need of a python compiler (from .py or .pyw to .exe).

the only ones i have come across are:

**- cx_freeze (doesnt work)**

**- py2exe (way too complicated)**

**EDIT:**
both of the programs above are complicated (to me) because you have to make all these setup files, and type in a bunch of parameters and commands to get them to work,i found something called gui2exe.py however i cant seem to get it to load correctly... any thoughts?

So what i was looking for was a program that you do not have to run through the python command line. Prefereably a stand alone program, that you can just select the file and select the output (.exe) and click convert. Nothing too complicated as i am just starting out.

The reason i want this is because i have a program that my friend wanted to take a look at but he doesnt want to download python in order to view it. Also i dont want him to be able to change the source code.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The already two know the main options. You're asking the wrong question, you should either (1) tell us **what** doesn't work with cx_Freeze so we can help resolve it or (2) ask for help to get started with py2exe. Also, you're propably expecting too much ("just select the file and the output" - many nontrivial programs have dependencies no program can detect statically).

Comment: ok your probably right on that part, and when i open cx_freeze it doesnt do anything, its just an extremely small batch file.. i really dont see how it could compile anything... also, i would like to know exactly what to type in if i were to compile "test.py" and output the .exe file to "F:\scripts\python"

Comment: py2exe is very simple. It's not "too complicated" unless your setup is complicated, but you say nothing about what makes it complicated.

Comment: I don't think any of them actually compiles anything.

Comment: and when it comes to py2exe it really looks like it could work however i have no clue how to use it. Ive read its documentation but it only gives you the parameters , not how to use them (examples)

Comment: well could you further explain how to use them?

Comment: "Also i dont want him to be able to change the source code." Unless that's because you stole the code from him and doesn't want him to know, this is a bad reason. In any case, you can then just ship the pyc-files.

Comment: What have you tried, what happened and what did you expect to happen? (Update your question with that info).
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: I gave an answer below, but my personal recommendation for your situation (which to some extent ignores the question as presented), is to work harder to persuade your friend to install Python. ;)  I doubt he will regret it:  The most likely outcomes are that he becomes a Python fan himself, or he uninstalls it.  No harm done either way, in my opinion.

Comment: @John Y hes not a computer person, like he doesnt do any form of programming, however, i told him i made a program in python that can draw a picture and he wanted to see it for himself, and he doesnt know much about computers so he wont believe me when i said that python wont give you viruses. (he doesnt really know the difference, he assumes that if you download any thing from someone else its a virus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pyinstallet might help...

however py2exe is not complicated...

take a look at this py2exe sample setup (from here, but it's italian, so i translated it http://bancaldo.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/python-py2exe-setup-py-sample/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, wx, os

# Se eseguito senza argomenti, crea l'exe in quiet mode.
# If executed without args, it makes the exe in quiet mode
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")

class FileBrowser(wx.FileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        wildcard = "Python files (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "Tutti i files (*.*)|*.*"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose the file", os.getcwd(),
            "", wildcard, wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            print(dialog.GetPath())
        self.file = dialog.GetPath()
        self.fin = open(self.file, 'r')
        dialog.Destroy()

class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        # info di versione
        self.version = "1.0.0"
        self.company_name = "Bancaldo TM"
        self.copyright = "no copyright"
        self.name = "py2exe sample files"

manifest_template = '''
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
     type='win32'
     name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT'
     version='9.0.21022.8'
     processorArchitecture='*'
     publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
         type="win32"
         name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
         version="6.0.0.0"
         processorArchitecture="*"
         publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
         language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
'''
# File Browser
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
fb = FileBrowser()
# Assegno il nome all'eseguibile di uscita
# Give the name at the exe file being created
textentry = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "name file EXE?",'','')
if textentry.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    destname = textentry.GetValue()

RT_MANIFEST = 24

test_wx = Target(
    description = "A GUI app",
    script = fb.file,     # programma sorgente dal quale creiamo l'exe
                          # source from wich we create the exe
    other_resources = [(RT_MANIFEST, 1, manifest_template % dict(prog="tried"))],
    icon_resources = [(1, "py.ico")],
#    dest_base = "prova_banco") # Nome file di destinazione
                                #Name Destination file
    dest_base = destname) # Nome file di destinazione

setup(
    data_files=["py.ico"],
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "ascii": 1,
                          "bundle_files": 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [test_wx],
    )
```

it inclused also a small graphic interface wich help you on choose the file ;)

EDIT:

this is a simpler sample, maybe it's more useful :)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    name = 'AppPyName',
    description = 'Python-based App',
    version = '1.0',
    windows = [{'script': 'Main.pyw'}],
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,'packages':'encodings','includes': 'cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject',}},
    data_files=[ 'gui.glade',]
    zipfile = None, 
)
```

STEP BY STEP TUTORIAL:

1-create a .py file, naming it, for example, 'hello.py', that has not a GUI
2- make a setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

notice the use of 'console' instead of 'windows', 'cause you have not a gui

then, move your hello.py file and your setup.py file in Python directory; then open the cmd,  and once you've arrived at the correct directory (usually C:\python2x), type:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

you're exe file will be in the dist directory. if some .dll are missing, simply download it and place in python directory.

once your program will be more complicated, it may require other instructions; look at the other 2 setup.py samples i've posted.
hope this help

Comment: ok so is this an example of a setup.py file? or an example of a program that the setup.py file can compile... and i tried running your script above and it didnt open , do i need to run it from the python cmd?

Comment: this is an example of setup.py file, even if you could write a much more simple one (i edited my code in order to show it) ;) have you installed wx? if doesn't work, try to add 'app.mainloop()' at the code ;)

Comment: no i havent installed wx, and also where in your script would i add 'app.mainloop()'?

Comment: ok so can you layout the step by step process of what i should do to compile a .py file

Comment: i did.... but the documentation is quite easy to understand ;)

Comment: ok thanks ill try it out! btw, when you say cmd do you mean the python command line or the windows shell command line? (and if python cmd, then python.exe or pythonw.exe?)

Comment: @daniel11: `cmd` usually means the Windows command line, because if you go to start, run, and type "cmd", it will give you the command prompt.

Comment: yea, but when i goto the cmd and type "python hello.py" it comes up saying that python isnt a command or internal batch file... so does that mean i set it up wrong?

Comment: ohh nvm i didnt realize that i had to have the python.exe program in the same directory as the file i wanted to open ahah

Comment: yeah, otherwise it say that python is not a command or internal batch file, because windows can't find it. you need to move to that directory first.. if you have no other problems, please accept the answer ;)

Comment: i still have one more problem, i compiled it and when i try to open the .exe file it wont open... ive tried opening as administrator ive tried re compiling it, ive tried moving it to a different directory... nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure it dont open at all? maybe is just a flashing window? (in this case you may add raw_input() at the end) are you using the exe you found in the dist directory? are you using th exe *in* the dist directory? what happen, exactly? it just don't open?

Comment: i click on it and then it opens a command line window for like a second (like you said "a flash") and i think it had some text on the window but then it closed again. ive tried to compile several programs now and i get the same result . i will try your raw_input() method now

Comment: ok so i tried compiling a program with a gui and now the .exe file will open , but it will also open a console window behind it which i wasnt expecting... and what i want is just one .exe file not all these extra files along with it. so is it possible to compile all of the files that the .exe file depends on into one .exe file? (stand alone program)

Comment: try to rename your .py file in a .pyw before compiling it. it should work. however, you can't get rid of the other files, because they contain python and the libreries...withou them your exe won't work. if you want make a setup.exe file, that will extract all needed files in the directory you want etc, try with InnoSetup.

Comment: @daniel so, for console application that need to show a text and are not in a loop, you have to add raw_input() at the end of the file to make the windows stay on giving you the time to see the output. if you have a gui application, renaming your .py file in .pyw will make it open without the python console.

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to use IronPython.  IronPython is another dialect of python that targets .NET, and works quite easily with MS Visual Studio.

Comment: +1 although I would recommend py2exe again. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

py2exe - Python to Windows EXE
py2exe converts your Python programs to standalone Windows executables that can run without your users needing to install Python. Note that this is not a native code compiler - your code is still interpreted. py2exe merely provides all the necessary pieces so that when your end users double-click on your executable, the Python interpreter will start up to interpret your code. py2exe is released under the Mozilla Public License

Comment: Some of this (the part that it's not compiled natively) may be interesting to know, but I don't think it adresses the question in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [gui2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/), it's a pretty good frontend to py2exe, pyinstaller, etc.

Comment: ok ive got gui2exe and it looks like it works but when i double click on the gui2exe.py file in the zip folder i downloaded, it doesnt open, and when i type "python GUI2exe.py" into the python command line, it comes up with a syntax error. how can i fix this?

Comment: Could you post the syntax error you're seeing?  Also check to make sure you've got all the packages installed you need - I think the only requirement for the GUI to at least load is wxPython but it's been a while since I've used the program.

Comment: ok ive tried typing "python gui2exe.py" into the cmd and now it says "no module <py2exe>" however ive installed and re-installed it like 20 times"

Comment: That's a weird one - it shouldn't be loading py2exe until after the GUI's fired up and you tell it to, seeing as it's a frontend to a bunch of different compilers.  What happens if you rename GUI2exe.py to GUI2exe.pyw?  That sometimes fixes the weird bugs you see in Python on Windows.

Comment: ok changing the extension to .pyw didnt do anything... also, when i try running it through the cmd using "python gui2exe.py" i get an error saying "Import error:DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application." Any ideas?

Comment: Try running "python -v gui2exe.py" to see if you can get any additional info on what's going on.  I did a quick Googlin' and the only other thing to come up that seemed relevant was to make sure that your Python folder is on your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something I would recommend to a beginner, but if you are comfortable with C/C++ compilers, you could try [Shed Skin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/).  If your Python source code meets certain requirements, Shed Skin can translate it into C++ and compile the C++ into a binary executable.

Comment: That's not exactly a _simpler_ solution than using py2exe...

Comment: @Robert Liffredo:  I don't disagree, but you never know what some people will find easier or harder.  I figured it was worth throwing another option out there.  Also, someone else looking up this question for a different ultimate purpose than the OP might find Shed Skin useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply provide your friend a ZIP file containing python.exe, the python libs, and your python application (in pyc) along with a batch to start python.exe with your script. Python is fairly easy to run without it being 'installed'.